# Is there a way to reduce antialiasing in QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, antialiasing, qpainter

It is a pretty simple question. Is there a way to reduce little bit `QPainter` antialiasing (not to turn off completely)? To increase it we have `QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing`. But what about deacrease?

Comment: Erk... what? Why do you want to do that? (Note that the "high quality" thing is only relative to the GL paint engine, where it enables multisampling)

Comment: Render twice with anti-aliasing on and off, then average the outputs?  You can even do a weighted average, giving you a continuum of anti-aliasing amounts!

Comment: @peppe I want to decrease a level of anti aliasing when I call `QPainter::drawPolyline` to decrease a CPU usage.

Comment: @Yakk ok, it is nice solution, but quite problematic. Anyway will keep it in mind. +1.

Comment: The implementation of antialiasing in Qt's raster engine has the same cost no matter what "amount" of antialiasing is performed. Your question should be rephrased: you don't care about amount of antialiasing, you want to make the raster paint engine perform faster when antialiasing is used. Ask that instead.

Comment: @KubaOber, agree it sounds better. Do you have an answer or solution or a piece of advice how to perfrom this?

Comment: @Mikhail You'd have to tell us exactly what you're doing, what your benchmarks are, how much faster you need it done, ideally post a code sample, etc. You know: the basics of a question that can be actually answered and is helpful to others. Remember that SO is not a help forum,it's a place for content that is useful to more than one person.